# Install plank in Xubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, plank

I use this command to install Plank:

```
sudo apt install plank
```

But I get this error over and over:

```
**The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 plank : Depends: libplank1 (= 0.11.89+git20200705.20c16a0b-0ubuntu1~20.04~ricotz1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.**
```

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy libplank1 plank` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `libplank1`:

```
sudo apt install libplank1
```

Not sure though if this will work.